# MySQL: Замена оператора IN

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! OpenCart 2.0, при фильтрации товаров делает примерно такой запрос: `... AND pf.filter_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)...`

1,2,3,4,5 - это ID фильтров. Запрос возвращает все товары, ID фильтров которых соответствуют **хотя бы одному** из 1,2,3,4,5. Мне нужно переписать запрос так, чтобы они соответствовали не одному, а **всем** фильтрам.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Без самого запроса сложно, но общий принцип пояснить можно.
Категории, судя по всему, джойнятся как многие-к-одному. И, соответственно, группируются. И вот  для этой груммировки надо добавить условие `HAVING count(1) = 5` - чтобы число совпадало с числом элементов в массиве.

Comment: вот так `IN(1,2,3,4,5) HAVING COUNT(1) = 5` ?